# Help with equation and explain to me?

Tags: polynomials

$5(-3x - 2) - (x - 3) = -4(4x + 5) + 13$ Solve for $x.$

Can anyone solve this equation and explain it to me? I don't understand this equation for some reason and I always keep getting different values.

Comment: Please show your work, step by step, so Readers can see where the mistakes occur.  As currently phrased, many will interpret this as a plea to do your thinking for you.

Comment: Not all equations *have* solutions.  And not all equations have just one.  This equation reduces to -16x - 7 = _16x - 7, (which further reduces to 0 = 0).  This equation is *always* true for all values of x.  So *all* values of x.  Every number is a soultion.

Answer (score 3):

Go ahead and multiply your numbers outside of the parenthesis, by the values inside. Make sure you keep track of your signs.

$5(-3x-2)$ will simplify as $-15x-10$

If you do the same for the other numbers and combine your x's and your integers, you will get a solid value for x. Once you are done, you can check your answer by putting your value for x back into the equation.

Comment: Except in this case you do NOT get a solid value for x.  You get a solid value for 0.  It turns out 0 = 0 (who would have guessed?  As far as x goes, you get x = x.  Which isn't very solid at all.

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct. I didn't solve the problem mostly because I wanted him to do so. But yeah, all values of x are solutions.